# How automatically add method to an existing unittest class in python unit?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have read [Adding a method to an existing object instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance/2982#2982) and I got it.

Now I have two directory and have some file, like this:

```
.
|--A
|  |--a_A.txt
|  |--b_A.txt
|--B
|  |--a_B.txt
|  |--b_B.txt
```

I need to compare **a_A.txt** and **a_B.txt**, **b_A.txt and b_B.txt**.

And I use `pyunit`, because A dirctory and B dirctory maybe have many file, and I want to compare at every turn that procuces a test* function, this function name is filename, like `test_a_A`.

I have version 1 code, like this:

```
def _p(lst):
    def wrapper(func):
        def action(self):
            for l in lst:
                func(self, l)
        return action
    return wrapper

class CTest(unittest.TestCase):
    expect = [] # A directory file list
    actual = [] # B directory file list

    @_p(lst=expect)
    def testAction(self, filename):
        self.do_compare(filename, actual[0]) # only example
```

If the code likes this, it have only one result `testcase`. But I have two `testcase`, so I need to dynamic produce `testcase` in addition to filename.

**EDIT**

Done! I use `setattr` to add dynamic attribute.

Comment: edit your post with your code so we can help you as efficiently as possible

Comment: @Clayton Hi, I have added some code with  `decorator`